# Removing/filtering properties of specific type from another

Tags: typescript

I'd like to do something like the following.  Consider we had a type:

```
interface MyInterface {
    stringProp: string,
    numberProp: number
}
```

I'd like to create a utility type which would, given another type (such as `number` or `string`) filter out properties of that type, like so:

```
/// Utility type, this is the thing I'm trying to define
type TypeFiltered<T extends object, V> = ...

// Apply to MyInterface, number properties only
type MyInterfaceNumberProperties = TypeFiltered<MyInterface, number>

// MyInterfaceNumberProperties is
// { numberProp: number }
```

I know I can get the full structure with `never` for the types I don't want with the following:

```
type ReplaceWithNever<T extends object, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? T[K] : never
}
```

But that's where I'm stuck, as for `MyInterface` that effectively produces a type with the following:

```
/// ReplaceWithNever<MyInterface, number>
{
    myString: never,
    myNumber: number
}
```

Is there a way to filter out items from `keyof ReplaceWithNever<T, V>` where `keyof ReplaceWithNever<T, V>` produces `never`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript 4.1 you can use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) (using an `as` clause) to filter out properties by remapping such keys to `never`:

```
// TS4.1+
type TypeFiltered<T extends object, V> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K]
}
```

In TypeScript 4.0 and below you would need to use something like the [`Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to filter properties, which you'd need to identify by *key* and not *value*... forcing you to do a more complicated operation like this:

```
type TypeFilteredOld<T extends object, V> = Pick<T, {
    [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
>;
```

Either way should produce the same type:

```
type MyInterfaceNumberProperties = TypeFiltered<MyInterface, number>
/* type MyInterfaceNumberProperties = {
    numberProp: number;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkBnMKUAcwAUoB7ABwC4KraAaEskAVwC2AI2gMW7ASOhEAvkSIB6RcgAqAZQAsAOgCMAaiJh0zFKpMQAYsAA2kKBAAmAHlXIIAD0ghH5ZI2EAKwgEMC5kADUAPmQAXkJeUgBtAGlkUGQAawh0Rhg1ZDg-VVSAXXcvCB8-COQAfmQ0yQgAN2hS9hKU0rkFZTUtbQAGAFojCzULaztoJwB5Gxc3T29ffyCQsMiY+LpgBEzXcOIyZFT0kCycvLVSkbrOsorVmvrG5Ga2qGRZJOzc-KqHpRADcCnGpjQWBwsEQEAAckJRFBxKYoGBgBA-PFzKZpvYnM4MNh7HgIOEpMiokoAFTIYyQ4kwsmI6QophojFYuIJU6UsQcyRI6Bg2TIGmKBQMlAAJQgzBscIA6sAwAALeGtaCuZ5VNYBYKhcLRHknMjnDL-G5Ax7dXXVSJvLrlT4yeQQsxTWwExwyxj8HxwYT+sA6lZ6vwGzbGna881pS3XQGFPxyhXK1UarVQI7bJ7hh0gbNvItfD6NDpqMq9IA)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is this:

```
type TypeFiltered < T extends object, V > = Pick < T, { [ P in keyof T ]: T[P] extends V ? P : never }[ keyof T ] >

type T = TypeFiltered < MyInterface, number > // { numberProp: number }
```

The longer answer is, it is built up as follows (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkBnMKUAcwAUoB7ABwC4KraAaEskAVwC2AI2gMW7ASOhEAvkSJh0zFABVlEAGLAANpCgQAJsgA8yVcggAPSCEPlkjYQCsICMF2QA1ZAD5kALzIdMAIANam5p4EyADawcigyGEQ6Iww5sgAuuyqsXRZljYQdg4+APwJkhAAbtDIsvEpaRkWhb4KSiqZQeoq2nrQRpEY2Pp4EJ5SolB+yAD084TI02JMbCtCMw2dGsHr0EoAcnCCEOQA8jB9EBdQR7X1ZhbWtvaOLm4e3nNBMfF0RIgZKpdKZHLmfKFV4ld4VKorR6zeSKPYADUC+xYh3QJzOl2uGjuDzqszMoxwsEQk020lm-kWy0o1BA9HW1VJUy2awkyAARKsoOJmHydqjusKcXjzgN9MNnkU3g4nK53J4fP4gpKoMdTucrjdiUjIqp1X4mqDWtldt0AJqY7W6-GyobGclYSkTLl0uaMgXcoXrPk2tQaF0GQwAYUYgmYjHIwEgJsVsOVnzVP01wVCEWenkduL15HD8qimb8IeQAC1MTcS1GY3GE0n3WNcNTvdsGUsYoLhZIAw0gA)):

First, by forming a type for an object with the same property names as a given object, but where the property types are either (i) the property names of the given object when they are of a specified type, or else (ii) `never`. This is from using conditional types with an index signature in a new object:

```
type PropertyNamesOfTypeOrNever < T extends object, V > = { [ P in keyof T ]: T[P] extends V ? P : never }

type X = PropertyNamesOfTypeOrNever < MyInterface, number > // { stringProp: never, numberProp: "numberProp" }
```

Second, from a type which is the union of property names where the property values  have a certain type, using the indexed access operator:

```
type PropertyNamesFiltered < T extends object, V > = PropertyNamesOfTypeOrNever < T, V >[ keyof T ]

type Y = PropertyNamesFiltered < MyInterface, number > // "numberProp"
```

And finally, using that union to filter out using the built in `Pick` type:

```
type TypeFilteredComposite < T extends object, V > = Pick < T, PropertyNamesFiltered < T, V > >

type Z = TypeFilteredComposite < MyInterface, number > // { numberProp: number }
```

Comment: The link to the playground has code that the playground says is not valid.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for taking a look.